# Azure Operation returned an invalid status 'Conflict'

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I am having below error while running powershell

```
$thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file $Path --certificate-password $(pwd) --name $env:APP_NAME --resource-group $env:RG_NAME --query thumbprint --output tsv)



{"Code":"Conflict","Message":"Another certificate exists with same thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx at location xxxxxx in the Resource Group xxxxxx.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Another certificate exists with same thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx at location xxxxxx in the Resource Group xxxxxx."},{"Code":"Conflict"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"53008","MessageTemplate":"Another certificate exists with same thumbprint {0} at location {1} in the Resource Group {2}.","Parameters":["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx"],"Code":"Conflict","Message":"Another certificate exists with same thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx at location xxxxxx in the Resource Group xxxxxx."}}],"Innererror":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to upload an existing certificate with a different certificate name, you get this error.                                                                                                                                     Running ARM template as part of CI/CD workflow (after doing the initial setup via portal) is the most common scenario. Uploading the same certificate into two distinct AppServicePlans is another common scenario (which are in the same WebSpace).
You can resolve this by changing the ARM template so that certificate resource name matches with what you have in the Resource Explorer. Alternatively, you can delete the old certificate and run the ARM template.
To obtain the Certificate Resource name, you can try the PowerShell scripts listed below.

```
$resourceGroupName = "SixShotRG"
$thumbprint = "78311D191030008F5D7EEDC0FCC295AFEED5DFD7"

$certificates = Get-AzResource `
 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `

 -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/certificates
Write-Host ("Looking for thumbprint "  + $thumbprint + "..."  )
Write-Host ("`tFound "  + $certificates.Count `
+ " certificates in ResourceGroup : "  `
+ $resourceGroupName `
+ $resourceGroup.Name)
foreach  ($certificate **in**  $certificates) {
 $cert = Get-AzResource `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/certificates `
-ResourceName $certificate.Name
if  ($thumbprint -eq $cert.properties.thumbprint) {
Write-Host ("`tFound our cert in "  `
+ $cert.properties.webSpace `
+ ' webspace')
+ Write-Host ("`tCert name is "  `
+ $cert.Name)
 Exit
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, found the certificate was manually added, caused error while running via pipeline. Removed and attached using pipeline. It was successful